# android app login with sails.js app

Tags: android, rest, authentication, server, sails.js

I have an android app with login, registration and medical data, which connect to sails.js app to upload the data. In sails app, i have models, 'Patient',etc. Basically the android app use GET and POST json to create and get the patients in sails app. the problem is that i dont have any security, every can send a POST to create a Pacient. So the question is how i can resolve the security problem, the android app should authenticate in the sails app and then can create and get Patient and upload the medical data.

i read that some people use socket.io, is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using websockets won't change anything about authorization. You could use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for this. Here is [an implementation of JWT for node.js](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken).

When a user login, generate a JWT for him. Then pass this JWT in the header of all the client's requests. Finally create a [sails policy](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) to check the JWT and allow access or not to controllers.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use passport.js in the backend?
you will have to create a user model, then add few methods to your rest api to create user/login etc and off you go.

sailsjs docs itself recommends this - http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies/sails-passport and provide link with a sample implementation - http://www.geektantra.com/2013/08/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js/.